# Low latency audio streaming with Icecast2 and mpd with raspbian

Tags: raspbian, audio

So I have two pi's, one with `icecast2` and both with `mpd`. I'm over a gigabit LAN connection, on the same switch, with the following settings in for `icecast.xml` (to do with latency):

```
<burst-on-connect>0</burst-on-connect>
```

in `mpd.conf` under `audio_output` for type `"shout"` on the `icecast2` pi:

```
bitrate "64"
```

in `mpd.conf` under `MPD Internal Buffering` on both pi's:

```
buffer_before_play "0%"
```

However I still have about a 2 to 3 second delay... If possible I would like it to get to less than 1 second. I'm personally not concerned with buffering or sound quality too much, just tinkering around to see how low i can get it.

Any advice is appreciated!!

Comment: do you stream a file or sound captured by a device? you may get better results when you stream the input directly (e.g. /dev/dsp) instead of compressing and decompressing the stream via icecast/player

Comment: No I grab it from files- I'll look into this to see if it works better.